# how to finish this java program about the collection

Tags: java, collections

Imagine you're developing a Pokemon game, and you need to implement the battle party mechanic. Recall that the player's party can hold at most 6 Pokemon. To simplify things, you want to implement it as an ArrayList containing 6 elements (1 for each Pokemon in the party), and to simplify things even further, you decide to avoid making a custom Pokemon class. Instead, you choose to represent each Pokemon as a HashMap with two keys: "Name" and "Level". The value associated with the key "Name" will be a String denoting the Pokemon's name, and the value associated with the key "Level" will be an Integer denoting the Pokemon's level.

TASK: Write a public static method called createParty that has one parameter of type String[] called names containing the Pokemon names, followed by a parameter of type int[] called levels containing the Pokemon levels (where names[i] and levels[i] are the name and level of Pokemon i in the party). It should return the party as a ArrayList> as described above

```
Sample Input:

Pikachu Venasaur Charizard Blastoise Lapras Snorlax
88 84 84 84 80 82
Sample Output:

Pikachu 88
Venasaur 84
Charizard 84
Blastoise 84
Lapras 80
Snorlax 82
```

my code as below, but it remind me with an error.

```
     public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> createParty(String[] names,int[] levels) {

         ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> party = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>(6);

         for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
             HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             hm.put(names[i], levels[i]);
             party.add(hm);

         }
         return party;

     }
```

the error as below

```
Failed test #1. The 'ArrayList' your 'createParty' method returned contained a 'HashMap' that was missing the "Name" key

Input:
Pikachu Venasaur Charizard Blastoise Lapras Snorlax
88 84 84 84 80 82
Your output:
MISSING_NAME
Correct output:
Pikachu 88
Venasaur 84
Charizard 84
Blastoise 84
Lapras 80
Snorlax 82
```

could you help to find which part is wrong,
thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead, you choose to represent each Pokemon as a HashMap with two keys: "Name" and "Level"

It would appear that it is expecting instead of

```
hm.put(names[i], levels[i]);
```

That you return the name and level with fixed keys:

```
hm.put("Name", names[i]);
hm.put("Level", levels[i]);
```